# Generate between interval while having overflow

Tags: command-line, arithmetic, random, numeric-data

```
echo INPUT | MAGIC > OUTPUT
```

INPUT: a random number that can be 0-999999999999 (so very big)

OUTPUT: a number between: 0-1023

MAGIC: a solution where the random smaller/bigger input is "converted" to the interval that the OUTPUT uses, so 0-1023

example:

```
INPUT: 0
OUTPUT: 0
```

another example:

```
INPUT: 1634
OUTPUT: 609
```

INPUT needs to "overflow" the OUTPUT.

Comment: In the example you have "INPUT: 0 OUTPUT: 0" however the rule above says "OUTPUT: a number between: 1-1024" - which one is correct? Also how was the second example generate because it looks like you have already worked it out.

Comment: It sounds like you're just talking about modulo division plus one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo Enter the INPUT:
read INPUT
echo OUTPUT: $(echo "$INPUT % 1024" | bc)
```